# How can I send data from query to my Email without email client android silently?

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent

I am developing an app in which I have a query form.I want that on clicking submit buttonan email should drop to my email account automatically without the use of email client in my phone.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `mail()` in a php script on a server which accepts parameters such as subject, body via POST method. From your application when the user takes action pass the collected data to the server via `HttpURLConnection`.